# Probability of getting a pair in Texas Hold'Em?

Tags: probability

So let's ignore the distinctions of pocket vs board, and flop vs turn vs river, and just talk about the 7 cards a single person has access to at the end of a round. This means we're also not worrying about selecting five out of seven, but only about whether the 7 cards contain a pair.

Also, I consider 7 cards to contain a pair if it contains at least two cards with the same rank, and don't care whether or not the 7 cards also contain a hand that is something other than a pair.

Wikipedia's page on poker probabilities uses frequencies of different possible 7-card sets to compute the probability of ANY pair as ~43.8%. Their formula is frequency of 7-card sets containing a pair divided by total frequency of 7-card sets, where the former equals ${\displaystyle \left[{13 \choose 6}-71\right]\times 6\times 6\times 990}$ and the latter equals $52 \choose 7$.

(I'm assuming wikipedia shares my definition for what containing a pair means, but feel free to correct me on that.)

I, using the hypergeometric series, compute the probability of a SPECIFIC pair to be ~8.3%. $(N=52, n=7, K=4, k=2)$.

I have three questions:

1. How do I obtain wikipedia's formula for frequency of sets containing a pair? The numbers 6, 71, and 990 seem to come out of nowhere. I don't understand it at all.
2. Is there a way similar to the hypergeometric series in which I can compute 43.8% without using the aforementioned formula?
3. How do I get from 8% to 43%? It's approximately $ \times 5.3$. How do I get that number? Is it some fraction like $ {n_1 \choose k_1} \over {n_2 \choose k_2} $?

Comment: Some clarity is needed.  Usually, in speaking of poker probabilities, saying a hand is a pair or a straight or whatever specifically precludes all superior hands.  Thus a hand with $4$ aces, is not a pair.  A Full House is not a pair.  A Royal Flush is neither a straight nor a flush.  And so on.  Is that what you mean or are you simply asking for the probability that none of the seven ranks coincide?

Comment: Should say:  the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability#Frequency_of_7-card_poker_hands) you mention, is clearly speaking of "a pair" in the sense I suggested (that is, it excludes all superior hands).  And, critically, the article is assuming that you have chosen the best $5$ card hand you can out of the $7$.  Thus we must exclude the case in which you have a pair, but it's better to go with the straight out of the $7$.

Comment: In a $7$-card hand, the best five cards are selected.  Therefore, we need to eliminate straights and flushes that arise when a single pair is taken.

Comment: @lulu I added an edit to try and clarify

Comment: Well.... Your notion of "pair" is not the same as Wikipedia's, for the reasons discussed.  So of course the probabilities are different.  It's easy to compute the probability you want...work backwards.  Compute the probability that no two ranks coincide.

Comment: @lulu easy for you maybe... should I post a separate question about how to compute the probability of at least two cards out of seven being of the same rank?

Comment: The first card can be anything.  The second must have a different rank, so probability $\frac {48}{51}$.  The third must have a different rank than either of the first two, so probability $\frac {44}{50}$. And so on.

Comment: Alternatively, note that the number of hands with no pair is $\binom {13}{7}\times 4^7$, as you can specify the $7$ ranks in your hand and then specify which suit each of the draws has.  And there are $\binom {52}7$ possible hands, so...  Good exercise to do it both ways and confirm that the results match.